# How does one add headings on "List of Figures" and "List of Tables"

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Column headers]

How would I go about augmenting the LoF and LoT to include a headings over the numbers?  Preferably without a package addition as I've worked hard to get the styling just so and I don't have time to learn how in another way.  The only packages I'm using are the following:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
```

**EDIT:**

@Christian - Please forgive me.  I am floundering a bit under the pressure, I I don't have much but it has been a LOT leg work to get this far.  I'm using LyX and have placed what breaks with packages like tocloft or titletoc in my preamble.tex which contains the following

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\def\degreeprogram#1{\gdef\@degreeprogram{#1}}
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}

%% Conform headers to school styling for headers -- turabian
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\mdseries\singlespace\centering}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}{12pt}{\MakeUppercase}

%First level; centered, boldface or italic type, headline-style capitalization
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\selectfont\bfseries\singlespace\centering}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

%Second level; centered, regular type, headline-style capitalization
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\selectfont\mdseries\singlespace\centering}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}

%Third level: flush left, boldface or italic type, headline-style capitalization
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\selectfont\bfseries\bf\singlespace}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}

%Fourth level: flush left, roman type, sentence-style capitalization
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\selectfont\mdseries\bf\singlespace}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}

%Fifth level: run in at beginning of paragraph (no blank line after, boldface or
% italic type, sentence-style capitalization, terminal period
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12pt}{16pt}\selectfont\mdseries\bf\singlespace}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}


% fixup TOC indentation and add . . . separator on Chapter lines  
\renewcommand*\l@chapter{\@dottedtocline{0}{1em}{1.5em}}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{4em}{2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{7em}{3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{10em}{4em}}



% Fixup chapter lines in TOC for all caps
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter .}\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

My school requires this for my thesis.  I feel it self evident as well but not my call.

Comment: You want us to help you maintain your layout, by not adding packages but do not provide any code we can work with in order to keep your layout? ;-) Ah, welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

Solved.  I picked my way through tocloft to find the answer.  The secret sauce was missing is

```
\@starttoc{lof}
```

I used like so

```
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{%
    \pagebreak\centering\MakeUppercase{\listfigurename}\par%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\MakeUppercase{\listfigurename}}%
    \mdseries{Figure\hfill{Page}}\par%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
}
```